# Need to take two text field values and add together to another field

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<p>First Name <input type="text" name="first_name"> Last Name <input type="text" name="last_name"></p>
<input type="hidden" name="screen_name" value="first_name + last_name">
```

How do I take what was typed into first_name and last_name fields and add them together to the screen_name so when the field is submitted, it inputs the values appropriately for the screen_name field?

I am looking for either a php or jQuery resolution.

Would this do the trick?

```
<?php $screen_name = $_POST["first_name"]." ".$_POST["last_name"]; ?>

  <input type="hidden" name="screen_name" value="<?php print $screen_name; ?>" />
```

Comment: Just a clarification: The php-code runs on the server at the time the page is downloaded by the browser. If the user change the first or last name, the php-code will not be run again and your hidden screen_name will always be empty. You have to concatenate the strings when you post the page to the server. And make sure you sanitize them at least by trimming them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP (on the server side):

$ScreenName = $_POST["first_name"]." ".$_POST["last_name"]

With jQuery (on the client side) you'll have to add ids to the fields to easier access them:

```
<p>First Name <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name"> Last Name <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name"></p>
<input type="hidden" name="screen_name" value="first_name + last_name" id="screen_name">
```

And then on the form submit event (or input field change event) set the screen_name field value:

```
var screenNameVal = $.("#first_name").attr("value")+" "+$.("#last_name").attr("value");
$.("#screen_name").attr("value",screenNameVal);
```

Comment: @bucabay has a very important point though that someone can turn off Javascript and submit their own value for screen name, so while possible with jQuery to do it ahead of time it's best with PHP server side

Comment: Never ever trust the user input. Always sanitize it. At least trim it (remove white space at the beginning and at the end). Even if javascript is great and useful, make sure your pages works as much as possible even when it's not available (the user may have disabled it).

Comment: I agree that if possible, all logic should be on the server side. In this case the PHP version is not only safer but even cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

You're better off leaving out the screen_name all together. Just concatenate the values from first_name and last_name at the PHP side.

```
<?php

$screen_name = $_REQUEST['first_name'].$_REQUEST['last_name'];

?>
```

If you use JavaScript, someone may just disable it and send you a screen name that isn't actually their first and last name.

Comment: Suggestions: Trim both the first_name and last_name since the user could have antecedently put spaces in them (and maybe put a space between the first and last name?) Maybe also make sure that the first and last name don't have characters below 31, no special chars, case-correction...

Answer (score 2):

I agree it should be server side, but just to answer your question:

```
var combinedName = $("input[name='first_name']").val() + $("input[name='last_name']").val();
$("input[name='screen_name']").val(combinedName);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $('input[name="firstname"], input[name="lastname"]').blur(function () {
            $('input[name="fullname"]').val(function () {
                return $('input[name="firstname"]').val() + ' ' + $('input[name="lastname"]').val();
            });
        });
    </script>
```